# TSLint. max-statements rule - is it available?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

I have found that natively TypeScript Linter does not provided with max-statements rule checking, instead of ESLint version - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-statements.

Maybe someone has know any polyfill or something else for max statements checking in TS?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`cyclomatic-complexity` TSLint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/cyclomatic-complexity/) which also counts the number of statements within a function.